# How to get echo to print only deleted file paths?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, echo

I'm trying to write a script to create mysqldumps daily in a directory as well as check all the backups in that directory and remove any older than 7 days that is going to run on cron.

So my functions work correctly, it's just my last echo command that is not doing what I want it to. This is what I have so far:

```
DBNAME=database
DATE=`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H\%M`
SQLFILE=$DBNAME-${DATE}.sql
curr_dir=$1

#MAIN
mysqldump -u root -ppassword --databases $DBNAME > $SQLFILE

echo "$SQLFILE has been successfully created."

#Remove files older than 7 days

for filepath in "$curr_dir"*
    do
        find "$filepath" -mtime +7 -type f -delete
        echo "$filepath has been deleted."
    done
exit
```

So the backup creations and removal of old files both work. But, my problem is that `echo "$filepath has been deleted."` is printing all files in the directory instead of just the files older than 7 days that were deleted. Where am I going wrong here?

**EDIT (Full solution):**

This is the full solution that wound up working for me using everyone's advice from the answers and comments. This works for cron jobs. I had to specify the main function's output filepath because the files were being created in the root directory instead of the path specified in Argument $1.

Thank you everyone for the help! The if statement also checks whether or not $1 is the specified directory I want files to be deleted in.

```
#Variables
DBNAME=database
DATE=`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H\%M`
SQLFILE=$DBNAME-${DATE}.sql
curr_dir=$1

#MAIN
mysqldump -u root -ppassword --databases $DBNAME > /path/to/db-backups/directory/$SQLFILE

echo "$SQLFILE has been successfully created."

#Remove files older than 7 days

for filepath in "$curr_dir"*
    do
        if [[ $1 = "/path/to/db-backups/directory" ]]; then
            find "$filepath" -mtime +7 -type f -delete -exec sh -c 'printf "%s has been deleted.\n" "$@"' _ {} +
        fi
    done
exit
```

Comment: I don't know bash, but it looks like your `FOR` loop is saying "If the filepath is older than 7 days, then delete it, and then regardless of whether the file is deleted, say `$filepath has been deleted`" You may consider adding some kind of "if" block or something to limit the echo piece, as well.

Comment: One way to do what @phroureo correctly suggests is to add `-exec echo '{}' "has been deleted" \;` to the `find` command instead of putting it on a separate line.

Comment: @phroureo, the bash code doesn't *know* if an individual deletion was successful -- that's all internal to `find`.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend adding some sanity-checking to `$1` -- at the very least, make sure it was specified, otherwise someone's likely to forget it (or run the script without realizing it needed to be specified), and purge everything older than 7 days from whatever the current directory happens to be.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I took heed of your advice. Nearly learned that the hard way, but what I did was add an if statement in my for loop to only delete files if $1 equates to the directory where the backups are in.

`for filepath in "$curr_dir"*
 do
  if [[ $1 = "/path/to/mysqldump/backups" ]]; then
   find "$filepath" -mtime +7 -type f -delete -exec echo '{}' "has been deleted." \;
  fi
 done
exit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge the `echo` into the `find`:

```
find "$filepath" -mtime +7 -type f -delete -exec echo '{}' "has been deleted." \;
```

The `-delete` option is just a shortcut for `-exec rm '{}' \;` and all the `-exec` commands are run in the sequence you specify them in.

Comment: `-exec sh -c 'printf "%s has been deleted.\n" "$@"' _ {} +` is a bit more efficient, running the smallest possible number of external processes (vs one `/bin/echo` per match).